# beamer encapsulating video

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I'm preparing some slides for a conference and i need to send the pdf to the steering committee. Is it possible in beamer, using multimedia, to encapsulate the video inside the pdf, i.e. avoiding to load it in the specified path, but giving only the pdf?

Comment: are you sure they will be able to play the video on the computer you will be presenting from? with the movie15 package embedding a video should work, however I had severe trouble every time I tried. If you will present from your own computer, I'd leave the video out.